# Cohort analysis by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to use `cohort` package to complete a cohort analysis on a dataset of consisting of individuals who have taken courses over a year. However, I would like to organize the cohort around the period and the course (i.e. Jan 2023 - psychology = COHORT 1, Jan 2023 - math = COHORT 2, Feb 2023 - psychology - COHORT 3). I was hoping that using `group_by(COURSE)` would do the trick but it didn't work.

The code below works but only organizes the cohorts around the date. (i.e. Jan 2023 = COHORT 1)

```
df <- data.frame(ID =rep(c('A12', 'B289', 'C34', 'D23'), each=4),
      DATE = rep(c("01/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023", 
                   "03/01/2023", "02/01/2023", "03/01/2023",
                   "03/01/2023","01/01/2023")),
COURSE =rep(c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B','A', 'B','A', 'B')))

df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")


install.packages("cohorts")
library(cohorts)

cohort_analysis<- df %>% 
  cohort_table_month(id_var = ID, date = DATE)
```

I would like to be able to do something like this to get the same analysis by date and course:

```
install.packages("cohorts")
library(cohorts)

cohort_analysis<- df %>% group_by(COURSE) %>%
  cohort_table_month(id_var = ID, date = DATE)
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the question well. But I would like to know for instance how many course people of cohort 1A took a a course in February. The long way of doing that would be to multiple cohort analysis individually focused on each course then merge all the resulting tables.

Comment: For instance the fist analysis would only have course A in January and all the courses in February and March. The second cohort analysis would have course B in January and all the courses in February and March and so on. All the results would be merged at the end. This would be the long way. I'm trying to find a more efficient approach.

Comment: See the updated answer. I am sure there's a cleaner way to loop through these, but this is what I could come up with.

Comment: P.S. you may wanna add this explanation as an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update:

Based on the comments posted by OP, it seems that they want to get multiple cohorts for each course and month while keeping all the rows from the other courses. Here, I am making multiple datasets in a loop based on the aforementioned criteria, and then loop over each to get the cohort analysis by month.

```r
library(cohorts)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(M_Y = format(as.Date(DATE), "%b %Y")) %>% 
  {unique(.$M_Y) ->> imy;
    unique(.$COURSE) ->> ico}

df1 <- list()
i <- 0
for (coi in ico) {
  for (myi in imy) {
    i <- i+1
    df1[i] <- list(filter({df %>% mutate(M_Y = format(as.Date(DATE), "%b %Y"))}, 
                          ((COURSE == coi & M_Y == myi) | COURSE != coi)) %>% 
                     mutate(COURSE = coi, Month_Year = myi))
  }
}

df1 %>% 
  map_dfr(., ~cbind(.x[1, c("COURSE", "Month_Year")], 
                    cohort_table_month(df = .x, id_var = ID, date = DATE)))
```

```
#>    COURSE Month_Year cohort Jan 2023 Feb 2023 Mar 2023
#> 1       A   Jan 2023      1        4        2        4
#> 2       A   Feb 2023      1        2        2        2
#> 3       A   Feb 2023      2       NA        2        2
#> 4       A   Mar 2023      1        2       NA        2
#> 5       A   Mar 2023      2       NA        2        2
#> 6       B   Jan 2023      1        4        2        4
#> 7       B   Feb 2023      1        2        2        2
#> 8       B   Feb 2023      2       NA        2        2
#> 9       B   Mar 2023      1        2       NA        2
#> 10      B   Mar 2023      2       NA        2        2
```

---

---

###### Original Answer:

Getting the cohorts for each course.

```r
library(cohorts)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_split(COURSE) %>%
  map_dfr(., ~cbind(.x[1, "COURSE"], cohort_table_month(.x, id_var = ID, date = DATE)))

#>   COURSE cohort Jan 2023 Feb 2023 Mar 2023
#> 1      A      1        2       NA        2
#> 2      A      2       NA        2        2
#> 3      B      1        2       NA        2
#> 4      B      2       NA        2        2
```

Comment: +1, FYI `map_dfr` has (unfortunately) been superseded as of 1.0.0. in favor of piping to `list_*` functions. `list_rbind` in this case.